# Difference between assign and modify array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just lost 2 days to find where the bug was in my code on angular2 project, working on service.ts file.
I found it! yeah... no. I just fixed it.
I'm here (on stack) to understand the difference between the working code and the bugged one because on my eye their behaviour is the same.

Here is the bugged:

```
for (let i = 0; i < quantita; i++) {
      this.a.p[inizio + i] = target;
    }
```

Here is the working:

```
this.a.p = this.a.p.map((giorno, index) => {
      if (index >= inizio && index < inizio + quantita) {
        return target;
      } else {
        return giorno;
      }
    });
```

this.a is a variable that refer to an array. the bug was that the changes affect not only the selected object of the array, but it applies on another one.
I debugged pretty everything, and this.a was the correct instance, the code is called just once (as it should be) and there isn't other code that makes this change on the object.

I think to gave all the info about the problem, if not tell me please.

Comment: In the first example, you are _modifying_ the array in `this.a.p`. In the second example, you are creating a _new array_ and assigning it to `this.a.p`. Those are very different things and it's not hard to imagine how those would produce different behaviors.

Comment: I recommend to put correct title to Your question to help others to find Your question and answer for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you hold an array in a variable, you hold a reference to the array. If you change a value in an array all references will 'see' the change:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = a; // same array in a different variable
for(let i =0;i< a.length;i++) a[i] = a[i] *2;

console.log(a); // [2;3;6]
console.log(b); // [2;3;6]
```

If you use `map` a new array will be created that contains the result of the mapping operation:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = a;
a = a.map(n => n * 2) // new array in a, b still has the same array

console.log(a); // [2;3;6]
console.log(b); // [1;2;3]
```

You can build a `for` version that will not change the original array if you create a new array and push into that (although I strongly recommend sticking with `map` I present this just for the sake of completeness):

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = a; // same array in a different variable

let tmp = []
for(let i =0;i< a.length;i++) tmp.push(a[i] *2);
a = tmp;

console.log(a); // [2;3;6]
console.log(b); // [1;2;3]
```

Comment: I know that, but my variable that is modified is not referred to the same object.
my situation is:
let array = [1,2,3,4];
let a = array[1];
let b = array[2];
b gets the changes that i give to a

Comment: @rever And the array contains numbers or some other sort of object ? With object this is expected, with numbers something else is probably going on ..

Comment: the array contains objects. ok ty, I'll pay more attention with copy and true copy

Comment: upvote my question pls... I have too many questions without upvote and I can't question again..... thats sad